# reading a lambda terms in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, lambda-calculus

I have a lambda terms defined as follows:

```
type Symb = String

infixl 2 :@

data Expr = Var Symb
        | Expr :@ Expr
        | Lam Symb Expr
        deriving Eq
```

And i need to write instances for `Read` and `Show` typeclasses, so that lambda-term will be shown as a valid term in Haskell syntax.

I' ve done `Show` and it seems pretty easy. but i have some troubles in `Read` class.

I wrote something like this, as a test

```
instance Read Expr where
   readsPrec _ = myReadsExpr

myReadsExpr :: ReadS Expr
myReadsExpr s = [(Lam "x" (Var "x"), b) | (a, b) <- lex s]
```

but in ghci i have

```
*Fp06> myReadsExpr "\\x -> x"
[(\x -> x,"x -> x")]
```

And it's ok, but when i do

```
*Fp06> read "\\x -> x" :: Expr
```

I get exception

```
*Fp06> read "\\x -> x" :: Expr
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Can you please tell me, what am i doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

UPD: Can you also help me with further implementation? I need to parse them in my type so term `\\x y z -> x (y z)` will be parsed in `Lam "x" (Lam "y" Lam "z" (Var "x" :@ (Var "y" :@ Var "z")))`

I do not understand, how to handle brackets, and how to parse the term. Right now i have `Read` implemented this way:

```
myReadsExpr :: ReadS Expr
myReadsExpr s = 
[(Lam var expr, thunk2) |   ("\\", rest)    <- lex s,
                            (var, thunk)    <- lex rest,
                            ("->", thunk1)  <- lex thunk,
                            (expr, thunk2)  <- myReadsExpr thunk1]
++
[(Var sym, t)           |   (sym, t)        <- reads s]
++
[(Var x :@ Var y, t1)   |   (x, t)          <- lex s,
                            (y, t1)         <- lex t]
```

Answer (score 3):

`read` throws an error if the second element in the tuple from `readsPrec` is nonempty. That second element represents the rest of the `String`, after what was parsed.